# MySQL values updated to max after CSV 2nd import

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a php script to import values from a CSV files to table1 and then using inner join to update a field of table2 from table1:

```
UPDATE table2 AS t2
INNER JOIN
  (
  SELECT field, id
  FROM table1  ) AS t1 ON (t2.id=t1.id)
SET t2.field = t2.field+t1.field;
```

however, if I perform two imports the fields that were updated in the first import and not in the second are being updated to max value 9999.999 , field type Decimal(7,3).
Any ideas why and what might a suitable fix be? 
P.S the values in the table1 are correct.

Comment: Add some example data, really nonexistent fields should be left out from update!

Comment: i have no problem with your query, may be you need left join then inner join

Answer (score 0):

use simple update syntax

```
UPDATE table2 AS t2, table1 AS t1
SET t2.field = t2.field+t1.field
WHERE (t2.id=t1.id)
```